# Change the Text of a Option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, html-select

How can I change the text of an option with jQuery?

I'd like to change Newest with Oldest in an option is a `<select>` element.

```
$('select option:contains("Newest")').changeText('Oldest');
```

`.replaceWith` would not work for me.

Thanks.

## ----Update----

If my script looks like this:

```
$('select option:contains("Newest")').text('Oldest');
$('select option:contains("Oldest")').text('Newest');
```

Then I'm canceling out the first script, however, that isn't what I want. I have two options one that reads "Newest" which I'd like to replace with "Oldest" and one that reads "Oldest"  which I'd like to replace with "Newest". How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Does [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) not work for you?

Comment: Your syntax is broken. Where did you find the `.changeText` method?

Comment: @amnotiam It was a placeholder to display what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: Use the method @XavierHolt pointed out, but fix your syntax by either removing the inner single quotes, changing them to double quotes, or escaping them.

Comment: @amnotiam Yes, I took care of that...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should start a new question but here's the answer:

```
$('select option:contains("Newest")').text('TEMPEST');
$('select option:contains("Oldest")').text('Newest');
$('select option:contains("TEMPEST")').text('Oldest');
```

Comment: This is an unneeded 3rd query of the dom.  Once you create a jquery object, it maintains the list of elements that it matched at the time of creation.  Simply save the jquery objects to a variable before modifying.  No need to query an extra time.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('select option:contains("Newest")').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);

   $this.text($this.text().replace("Newest","Oldest"));    
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eSa5p/

EDIT: Answer to the new question:

```
var $newest = $('select option:contains("Newest")');

$('select option:contains("Oldest")').text('Newest');
$newest.text('Oldest');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eSa5p/3/

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me, although it would've been preferred

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#mySelect option").html(function(i,str){
  return str.replace(/Newest|Oldest/g,  // here give words to replace
     function(m,n){
         return (m == "Newest")?"Oldest":"Newest";  // here give replacement words
     });
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/eSa5p/2/

Answer (score 3):

Change text of the selected option:

$("#select").find("option:selected").text('Newest');

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by a simple script

```
$("option[value=optionvalue]").html('New text');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select option:contains("Newest")').addClass('changeToOldest');
$('select option:contains("Oldest")').addClass('changeToNewest');
$('.changeToOldest').text('Oldest').removeClass('changeToOldest');
$('.changeToNewest').text('Newest').removeClass('changeToNewest');
```

Comment: You are querying the DOM 4 times when twice is all that is needed.  Once you create a jquery object, it maintains the list of elements that it matched at the time of creation.  Simply save the jquery objects to a variable before modifying.  No need to query an extra 2 times, and add and remove classes unnecessarily .