# Change the existing value in a select/option dropdown with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just basically want to change the first value of "Select" to more meaningful, as in "Select Category". This needs to be done through JQuery.

### Here is the HTML

```
<select data-facet="field" id="ajax-facets" name="field_" class="form-select processed">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="Do Something">Do Something</option>
      <option value="Did Something">Did Something</option>
</select>
```

How can I do it through JQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the Text of a Option with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459073/change-the-text-of-a-option-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the Text:

```
$('option[value=0]').text('Select Category')
```

To change the value:

```
$('option[value=0]').val('Select Category')
```

To change both of them, before (the page complete to load)

```
$(function(){
    $('option[value=0]').text('Select Category').val('Select Category')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way, I can do it when this select changes?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ajax-facets option:first').attr('value','meaningful');
```

or

```
$('#ajax-facets option[value=0]').attr('value','meaningful');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple:

```
$(function(){
    $("#ajax-facets option:first").text("Select Category");
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsx85/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to change the text of the first `<option>`.

```
$('option[value="0"]').text('Select Category');
```

However, I'm not sure why you need to do this with jQuery. The problem is a little bit unclear to me.